# Solve $\cos 2x = \frac{2x}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

I'm trying to solve for $x$ in the following equation: $$\cos 2x = \frac{2x}{3}$$
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical or symbolical solution?

Comment: The given equation doesn't have any analytic solution.However, you can use numerical methods to find the roots of given equation.

Comment: Degrees or radians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a transcendental equation, so it doesn't have any "nice" solutions - typically, one investigates solutions by drawing the graphs of $f(x)=\cos(2x)$ and $g(x)=\frac{2}{3}x$ and noting where they intersect, or use numerical methods.

You could write $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ but this doesn't get you any closer to a solution.

See [the Wolfram Alpha page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(2x)%3D2%2F3x) for the solutions and the graph of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was hoping I could avoid using a graphical method, I'm always uncomfortable with their margin of error.

So there is no algebraic method of solving it? Is it just a case of trial and error with a calculator?

Comment: @Moofish The graphical method is just to get an overview (typically when you have to determine how many solutions there are) - numerical methods is what you should use to get the solutions. A normal calculator probably won't have this feature (although it could), so I'd use some computer software, like Mathematica or Maple, or Wolfram Alpha (which is free and online).

Comment: @Moofish Did you figure it out? Otherwise, let me know. Since you're new to the site (and since I have no shame :P) I'll just let you know that if a given answer answers your question satisfactorily, you can "accept" it (by clicking on the little tick below the up/down-vote arrows), and make the answerer very happy. Cheers!

Comment: I believe I understand now - thank you for your help! :)